# Normalise weights to produce midrange function signal

Tags: neural-network, normalization

I'm making a multilayer perceptron and I need to choose weights for input -> hidden unit. Our lecture said:

> Aim is to select weight values which produce midrange function signals
>
> Select weight values randomly from uniform probability distribution
>
> Normalise weight values so number of weighted connections per unit
>     produces midrange function signal

I'm not sure what he means by midrange function signal. So if weights for unit 1 is [0.5 0.9 0.1], do I just take the sum and divide each weight by the sum? Also is it for each input unit or output unit?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Weight initialization

**Midrange values**
The weights should be initialized within such an interval that a learning algorithm should easily observe the concequences of manipulating a set of weights. By selecting weights from a small interval, the learning algorithm would only have to alter the weights by a small delta to observe a change in the output signal.

**Uniform distribution**
It is preferred to initialize the weights by selecting random variables from the range [-0.1, 0.1]. By statistical intuition, we may infere that choosing the weights uniformly from an "symmetric" interval around 0 will indeed imply that the average signal would approach the mean value. Eg:

```
weights = [-0.05, -0.05, 0, 0.1]
signal = 0.7
average(weights * signal)  = 0.7
```

Comment: cool but how do i normalise the uniformly initiated weights? don't get it.

Comment: The only thing you need to do, is to uniformly initialize all the weights within the interval `[ -0.1, 0.1 ]`. If you're using NumPy: `np.random.uniform( -0.1, 0.1, size=(1, n_weights))`

Comment: Nah I don't think it should be between -0.1 and 0.1. It should be in [-sqrt(6/(fan-in+fan-out)), sqrt(6/(fan-in+fan-out))]

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you include the "fan out" degree in your interval calculation?